# Laravelのルート設定について

Tags: php, laravel

現在、以下のようなルートの設定で

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Router;

Admin::registerHelpersRoutes();

Route::group([
'prefix'        => config('admin.prefix'),
'namespace'     => Admin::controllerNamespace(),
'middleware'    => ['web', 'admin'],
], function (Router $router) {

$router->get('/', 'HomeController@index');
$router->resource('section', SectionController::class);

});
```

http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/section
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/section/create
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/section/1/edit

などでアクセスできるようになっているのですが
例えば新たに画面を作成し
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/section/batch_create
といったような形でアクセス可能にするにはどのようにすればよいのでしょうか？
一括でデータをインサートできるような画面を作成したいのですが

単純にコントローラに

```
public function batch_create()
```

するだけでは駄目でした・・。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
Route::group([
  'prefix'        => config('admin.prefix'),
  'namespace'     => Admin::controllerNamespace(),
  'middleware'    => ['web', 'admin'],
], function (Router $router) {

  $router->get('/', 'HomeController@index');
  $router->resource('section', SectionController::class);
  $router->get('selection/batch_create', 'SelectionController@batchCache'); // 追加

});
```

のようにアクション毎にルートを追加します。(提示されている条件だとこのほかpostのルートも必要かも)
詳しくは[ドキュメント](https://readouble.com/laravel/5.5/ja/routing.html)を。